# How to cut brick using polygon?

Tags: r, polygon, cut, raster

I have a brick file of the bioclim variables, the brick was merged from four 30sec tile brick, so it is a little bit large. I would like to get the brick file of my research area by cutting it using a polygon as boundary. What should I do? Otherwise, if it is not possible to do with brick, can I do it with raster?

Thanks in advance~

Marco

Comment: What is the format? Raster or adehabitat may do it, and I have some customized functions for dealing with .asc bioclim files.

Comment: It is raster or brick from raster package, also know as "grd". It is the default format of raster package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `extent()` if you want to crop the brick to a smaller rectangle. Also `drawExtent()` if you would rather choose by clicking.

EDIT: Since you used the terms "cut" and "mask" I am not sure I have understood correctly, but here are two ways that might help. You could even use both.

```
# an example with dimensions: 77, 101, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlayers)
myGrid_Brick <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

# a simple polygon within those dimensions
myTriangle_P <- Polygon(cbind(c(10, 80, 50, 10), c(10, 20, 65, 10)))
myTriangle_Ps <- Polygons(list(myTriangle_P), "fubar")
myTriangle_SP <- SpatialPolygons(list(myTriangle_Ps))
myTriangle_Ras <- rasterize(myTriangle_SP, myBrick)

# this will crop a brick to minimal rectangle that circumscribes the polygon
# extent(myCrop) is smaller than extent(myGrid) but no values are changed
myCrop_Brick <- crop(myGrid_Brick, myTriangle_SP)

# while this converts every coordinate that is NA in
# the mask to become NA in the returned brick
# while leaving the brick extent unchanged
myMask_Brick <- mask(myGrid_Brick, myTriangle_Ras)
```

Comment: Thanks Jonw! I think the crop(), extent() or drawExtent() is not for constraining the "bounday" or "Mask" but only for extent, that is the four corner of the grid. In another word, I want to know is there any way that all my steps can only take effects within that boundary?

Comment: Thanks again jonw! I think mask is the one I need!

Comment: @Marco: If this is the right answer, you can mark it for future users to see, by clicking the checkmark next to the number of votes. Also, I will get some points if you accept my answer. :)